# iPhone is not backing up to iCloud

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup

My iPhone 6S on IOS 9.3.2 has been set in iTunes so that it automatically backs up to iCloud. However it only backs up if I manually choose to do so from the iPhone.

The phone is charged at night and has a working WiFi connection, it is running a sleep monitor app.

Why is it not backing up and what do I need to do to make it do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind is because your device is not locked.
As stated in [this Apple document](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203977#icloud) that in order to "Automatically back up with iCloud Backup"

- Make sure that iCloud Backup is turned on in Settings > iCloud > Backup
- Connect your device to a power source
- Connect your device to a Wi-Fi network
- *Make sure that your device's screen is locked*
- Check that you have enough available space in iCloud for the backup

Comment: Has this always been true - for earlier versions did the backup occur even when locked? It used to work for me so I want to check what I have changed

Comment: In a previous revision of this document (Jan 15, 2015) Apple did not specify much details on all the details that needs to be done in order to have it backed up so I can't really prove as what it used to be but if I'm not mistaking that it didn't backup if the phone was unlocked but I'm not 100% certain about this nor can I test it since most of my devices are already on iOS10

Comment: Ok it ws the same - the battery has improved so I don't connect during the day which I had to for my old phone so that was when it backed